# Regex match even number of characters between two characters

Tags: regex, character, match

Say I have the following string:

> Something before _The brown "fox" jumped over_ Something after

I want to capture what's between `_` and `_`, but *only* if there is an even number of quotes `"` between them. So the above case will be a match.

From the following, only the bold ones should be matched:

> Some text _fir"st part_ and other text **_seco"nd t"est_** and more **_thir"d" "t"est_**

Note that the second and third ones have 2 and 4 quotes, respectively.

I've tried to do it but I've not been very successful: `_  (?= [^_]* " [^_]* " [^_]* _)* .*?  _` The spaces are added for readability.

I'm using PHP if it's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
_(([^"_]*"){2})+[^"_]*_
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/bN9pF1

Comment: One more question, what if I want to allow `_` between the matches. Your regex exception is `[^"_]` but say I want to allow `_`... I'm looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/rayt/6CcKp/embedded/result/

Comment: That will change the problem completely because this regex is solving problem of even # of quotes between 2 underscores. By allowing one `_` inside 2 `_` that even # of quote problem won't stand. Do you see my point,

Comment: Okay, you're absolutely right. It is a different problem. So how would you match an even number of quotes bounded by any number of underscores?

Comment: Getting very late here, I will come back to this problem in morning.

Comment: No problem. I fiddled around and got the solution: http://regex101.com/r/xR2vO9 Thanks again!